# How can I solve the Swing Calculator GUI Decimal Error?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have been working on my swing calculator GUI, but when it comes to the use of decimals, I seem to have some bugs. For instance, when you subtract a non decimal from a decimal the results automatically turns out to be negative. Furthermore, the calculator doesn't seem to be able to calculate decimal and non-decimal figures together. I was wondering whether you guys could take a look at it and give me some feedback. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class CalculatorEvolved extends JFrame {
    
    private int OP4 = 0;
    boolean secondOp, subtraction, multiplication, division;
    boolean comma = false;
    boolean firstOp = true;
    private double a, b;
    private double divisionA, divisionB, commaSum1, commaSum2;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JButton btnAddition;
    private JButton btnSubtraction;
    private JButton btnMultiplication;
    private JButton btnDivision;
    private JButton btnSquared;
    private JButton btn0;
    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JButton btn3;
    private JButton btn4;
    private JButton btn5;
    private JButton btn6;
    private JButton btn7;
    private JButton btn8;
    private JButton btn9;
    private JButton btnEquals;
    private JButton btnClear;
    private JButton btnComma;
    private ArrayList<String> operandOne = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> operandTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    private String sum1 = "";
    private String sum2 = "";
    

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CalculatorEvolved frame = new CalculatorEvolved();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CalculatorEvolved() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 345, 382);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(16, 6, 304, 29);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        
        btn8 = new JButton("8");
        btn8.setBounds(16, 47, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn8);
        btn8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn8);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn8);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        
        btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setBounds(16, 199, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn2);
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn2);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn2);
                }
            }
        });
            
        
    
        
        btn5 = new JButton("5");
        btn5.setBounds(16, 120, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn5);
        btn5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn5);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn5);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        
        btn0 = new JButton("0");
        btn0.setBounds(16, 272, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn0);
        btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn0);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn0);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        btn9 = new JButton("9");
        btn9.setBounds(106, 47, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn9);
        btn9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn9);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn9);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        btn6 = new JButton("6");
        btn6.setBounds(106, 120, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn6);
        btn6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn6);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn6);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setBounds(106, 199, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn3);
        btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn3);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn3);
                    
                }
            }
        });
        
        btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setBounds(106, 272, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn1);
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn1);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn1);
                    
                }
        
                
        
            
            }});
        
        btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR");
        btnClear.setBounds(196, 47, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnClear);
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lblNewLabel.setText("");
                sum1 = "";
                sum2 = "";
                firstOp = true;
                secondOp = false;
                operandOne.clear();
                operandTwo.clear();
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                divisionA = 0;
                divisionB = 0;
                OP4 = 0;
                subtraction = false;
                multiplication = false;
                division = false;
                comma = false;
                commaSum1 = 0;
                commaSum2 = 0;
                
                
                
            }
        });
        
        btn7 = new JButton("7");
        btn7.setBounds(196, 120, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn7);
        btn7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn7);
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn7);
                }
            }
        });
        
        btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn4.setBounds(196, 199, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btn4);
        btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    operandOneMethod(btn4);
                    
                    
                }
                
                if (secondOp) {
                    operandTwoMethod(btn4);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        btnComma = new JButton(",");
        btnComma.setBounds(196, 272, 78, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnComma);
        btnComma.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (firstOp) {
                    comma = true;
                    sum1 += ".";
                    lblNewLabel.setText(sum1);
                    operandOne.add(btnComma.getText());
                    System.out.println(operandOne);
                }
                if (secondOp) {
                    comma = true;
                    sum2 += ".";
                    if (OP4 ==1) {
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " + " + sum2);
                    }
                    else if (subtraction) {
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " - " + sum2);
                    }
                    else if (multiplication) {
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " * " + sum2);
                    }
                    else if (division) {
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " / " + sum2);
                    }
                    
                    operandTwo.add(btnComma.getText());
                    System.out.println(operandTwo);
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        btnAddition = new JButton("+");
        btnAddition.setBounds(286, 47, 53, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnAddition);
        btnAddition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstOp = false;
                
            
            if (!comma) {
                lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " + ");
                a = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
            }
            
                
            else if (comma) {
                commaSum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " + ");
                
                
            }
                
            secondOp = true;
            OP4++;
            
                
            
            }
        });
        
        btnSubtraction = new JButton("-");
        btnSubtraction.setBounds(286, 120, 53, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnSubtraction);
        btnSubtraction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                firstOp = false;
                
                
                if (!comma) {
                    lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " - ");
                    a = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                }
                
                    
                else if (comma) {
                    commaSum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                    lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " - ");
                    
                    
                }
                    
                    
                    
                secondOp = true;
                subtraction = true;
                    
                
                
            }
        });
        
        btnMultiplication = new JButton("X");
        btnMultiplication.setBounds(286, 199, 53, 41);
        
        getContentPane().add(btnMultiplication);
        btnMultiplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                firstOp = false;
                
                
                if (!comma) {
                    lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " X ");
                    a = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                }
                
                    
                else if (comma) {
                    commaSum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                    lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " X ");
                    
                    
                }
                
            
                    
                    
                    
                secondOp = true;
                multiplication = true;
                
            }
        });
        
        btnDivision = new JButton("/");
        btnDivision.setBounds(286, 272, 53, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnDivision);
        btnDivision.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                firstOp = false;
                
                
                
                if (!comma) {
                    lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " / ");
                    a = Integer.parseInt(sum1);
                }
                
                    
                else if (comma) {
                    commaSum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum1);
                    lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " / ");
                    
                    
                }
                    
                    
                    
                secondOp = true;
                division = true;
                
            }
        });
        btnEquals= new JButton("=");
        btnEquals.setBounds(286, 313, 53, 41);
        getContentPane().add(btnEquals);
        btnEquals.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
                
                if (OP4==1) {
                    if (comma) {
                        commaSum2 = Double.parseDouble(sum2);
                        double sum = commaSum2 + commaSum1;
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " + " + commaSum2 + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    else {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(sum2);
                    double sum = a+b;
                    lblNewLabel.setText(a + " + " + b + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    }
                
                
                if (subtraction) {
                    if (comma) {
                        commaSum2 = Double.parseDouble(sum2);
                        double sum = commaSum2 - commaSum1;
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " - " + commaSum2 + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    else {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(sum2);
                    double sum = a-b;
                    lblNewLabel.setText(a + " - " + b + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                }
                if (multiplication) {
                    if (comma) {
                        commaSum2 = Double.parseDouble(sum2);
                        double sum = commaSum2 + commaSum1;
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " X " + commaSum2 + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    else {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(sum2);
                    double sum = a * b;
                    lblNewLabel.setText(a + " X " + b + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    
                }
                if (division) {
                    if (comma) {
                        commaSum2 = Double.parseDouble(sum2);
                        double sum = commaSum2 + commaSum1;
                        lblNewLabel.setText(commaSum1 + " / " + commaSum2 + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                    else {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(sum2);
                    double sum = a/ b;
                    lblNewLabel.setText(a + " / " + b + " = " + x.format(sum));
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        
        
    }
    
    private void operandOneMethod(JButton x) {
        sum1 += x.getText();
        lblNewLabel.setText(sum1);
        operandOne.add(x.getText());
        System.out.println(operandOne);
        
        
    }
    
    private void operandTwoMethod(JButton x) {
        sum2 += x.getText();
        lblNewLabel.setText(sum2);
        operandTwo.add(x.getText());
        System.out.println(operandTwo);
        
        if (subtraction) {
            lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " - " + sum2);
            
        }
        if (OP4==1) {
            lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " + " + sum2);
            
        }
        if (multiplication) {
            lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " X " + sum2);
        }
        if (division) {
            lblNewLabel.setText(sum1 + " / " + sum2);
        }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: JFrame is what I meant vs swift**

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Dont give "vague" descriptions for "not working examples". Instead: give us specific examples of numbers that do not work, including your expectations. And, very important for yourself: learn to separate your problems. Before you start coding a huge GUI calculator ... start with writing basic java code, just a main method that does the kind of computations that you want your calculator to be doing. Ensure that all of that code behaves like you expect it. And **then**, when you really understand how to get the "math" working .... then add the GUI parts around it.

Comment: What you are doing is: building things on a base that isn't solid. And now we should come in and tell you whether your problem lies in the GUI part (maybe you are just parsing your numbers the wrong way) ... or in the actual computations. And as said, without specific examples, that requires a lot of work from your readers. So, focus on your actual problem, and tell us clearly what it is, instead of assuming that people here are wanting to spend half an hour to figure such stuff from your code.

Comment: okay understand thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is debug your code, i.e. use a debugger to run it. Every good IDE has a debugger.

You would see that this line of your code is wrong:

```java
double sum = commaSum2 - commaSum1;
```

It should be:

```java
double sum = commaSum1 - commaSum2;
```

You want to subtract the second operand from the first.

Refer to the `ActionListener` for `btnEquals`.